# Asking a Complicated Question with little knowledge

Tags: discussion

I am relatively new to Python, and have a program that I have struggled to fix a small bug on for days. I've narrowed it down to two or three possible causes, but do not know enough about the language to choose one. When asking for help solving my issue, should I simply link to the project and list the lines between which the possible issues are, or would it be better to include the possibly offending sections with my question? Linking to the project on Repl.it might overwhelm some people but provides important context, lest I missed something, but copy-pasting what I think is the issue is more concise.

Comment: The question must be self-contained, so linking to code is not good. What you need to do is create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The link contains all the information you need to ask a debugging question.

Comment: How did the [ask], [help] & google hits searching meta.stackoverflow.com not already answer this for you?

Answer (score 10):

Providing link to a code is not an acceptable way to represent code inline in the questions - the "debugging questions requires MRE inline in the post" is exact close reason that will be used.

If you are unable to create good [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is too early to ask question. Your options really are

- pay someone to sort it out for you
- create reasonably sized MRE
- close bug as "won't fix"